# Nextjs13 Graphql apollo config

Tags: next.js, apollo, next.js13

I am trying to set up a graphql frontend application with nextjs13 but with the new folder structure as there ins't _app.tsx I am wondering how to setup

Before we use to wrap the entire app like this

```
 <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </ApolloProvider>
```

Now how to set up that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do now is leverage the layout functionnality of the new nextjs 13 routing.

Your `_app.js` now becomes the root layout, a `layout.js` file that must be placed at the base of the app directory.

As any file in this directory, they will be treated as server component by default, which will prevent your Provider to work. Therefore, you need to create a component that will specify "use client" and then call it inside the root layoutfeed it the provider that will then be shared by the whole application.
Example code below:

```
// /apollo/ApolloProvider.js

"use client";

import { ApolloProvider as Provider } from "@apollo/client";
import { client } from "./client";

export const ApolloProvider = ({ children }) => (
  <Provider client={client}>{children}</Provider>
);
```

```
// /app/Layout.js

import { ApolloProvider } from "apollo/ApolloProvider";

const RootLayout = ({ children }) => (
  <ApolloProvider>{children}</ApolloProvider>
);

export default RootLayout;
```

Comment: I got TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Symbol(__APOLLO_CONTEXT__)') with this approach.

Comment: Does treating the root as "client" make all the routes teat as client components?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer doesn't work when I have attempted it like that. As mentioned in the comments this:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Symbol(APOLLO_CONTEXT)')`
Is the resulting error.

I found doing this works:

```
// /apollo/ApolloProvider.js

"use client";

import { ApolloProvider as Provider } from "@apollo/client";
import { client } from "./client";

export const ApolloProvider = ({ children }) => (
  <Provider client={client}>{children}</Provider>
);
```

```
// /app/Layout.js

import { ApolloProvider } from "apollo";

const RootLayout = ({ children }) => (
  <ApolloProvider>{children}</ApolloProvider>
);

export default RootLayout;
```

Comment: Just a side note: keep in mind that both files you mentioned should have a .jsx extension.